# I can't send form data to Python Jupyter

Tags: python, python-requests, jupyter, screen-scraping

I try to build a python script which sends a POST with parameters for extracting the result, but I don't know where is my problem or why I can't get the page result with the html that I need...

```
import requests

url = ('https://ar.ec.universal-assistance.com/cotizar-asistencia-al-viajero')

data = {
    '__RequestVerificationToken':'QWsTn0wqFmW9_jFfaBuuOjaWM4TE2Xk1XGn-oDTp0TENBO725YSkGnK8WeiAN53-jiPnjTDJ6zbZQjb6SzpprdCT4OlJg9jjZJKx1Wh7fGkZ5yCLkArUWCp6AIwq0t12gsonhP3orHzFJ2_1YqvIfJMcnzn2aXCb1-ZrDOzHM701',
    'CCTLD':'.ar',
    'CodigoOrganizacion':"",
    'CodigoConvenio':"",
    'OcultarTipoViaje':'false',
    'CantidadPasajeros':1,
    'CantidadDias':3,
    'Origen':'ARGENTINA',
    'Destino':'Centro america/Caribe',
    'TipoViaje':'Un viaje',
    'FechaInicio':'20/06/2019',
    'FechaFin':'22/06/2019',
    'Edad1':27,
    'Edad2':"",
    'Edad3':"",
    'Edad4':"",
    'Edad5':"",
    'Edad6':"",
    'Edad7':"",
    'Edad8':"",
    'Edad9':"",
    'Edad10':"",
    'Email':'no@no.com',
    'Nombre':'PEDRO',
    'Apellido':'PEREZ',
    'CodigoArea':800,
    'NumeroTelefono':9997777,
    'dr':"",
    'cn':'(direct)',
    'cs':'(direct)',
    'cm':'(none)',
    'ck':'(not set 5)',
    'cc':'(not set 5)',
    'ua':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
    'ref':'ar.ec.universal-assistance.com',
    'sr':'1366x768',
    'vp':'1366x728'
}
resp = requests.post(url = url, data = data )

print(resp.text)
```

And I tried:

```
import requests

url = ('https://ar.ec.universal-assistance.com/cotizar-asistencia-al-viajero')

header = {
":authority": "ar.ec.universal-assistance.com",
":method": "POST",
":path": "/cotizar-asistencia-al-viajero",
":scheme": "https",
"accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
"accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"accept-language": "es-ES,es;q=0.9",
"cache-control": "max-age=0",
"content-length": "921",
"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"cookie":"__cfduid=db577552fb94c6b34d51ff081f56060601559763003; _ga=GA1.2.1051767382.1559763017; _fbp=fb.1.1559763016835.1821187230; ASP.NET_SessionId=zirpp0zdbsvt4p102zvfknic; __RequestVerificationToken=RuGNfaFUJxBI4FDOaVsMJBdBNwbqzUt_AMjdUu6Am3T6kpBrZ5__wM8CiDO3Ttw6z6iBseVrGvzsyD-GCoWI2XRuhHpJB3-qu7qXvjoDu3NQL6onXupDL1E4ZkUXuHpDSPi0mjQ7F5PSFf2l_SGtDA2; _gid=GA1.2.1308535569.1560799988; _gat=1",
"origin": "https://ar.ec.universal-assistance.com",
"referer": "https://ar.ec.universal-assistance.com/cotizar-asistencia-al-viajero",
"upgrade-insecure-requests": 1,
"user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"         
},

data = {
    '__RequestVerificationToken':'QWsTn0wqFmW9_jFfaBuuOjaWM4TE2Xk1XGn-oDTp0TENBO725YSkGnK8WeiAN53-jiPnjTDJ6zbZQjb6SzpprdCT4OlJg9jjZJKx1Wh7fGkZ5yCLkArUWCp6AIwq0t12gsonhP3orHzFJ2_1YqvIfJMcnzn2aXCb1-ZrDOzHM701',
    'CCTLD':'.ar',
    'CodigoOrganizacion':"",
    'CodigoConvenio':"",
    'OcultarTipoViaje':'false',
    'CantidadPasajeros':1,
    'CantidadDias':3,
    'Origen':'ARGENTINA',
    'Destino':'Centro america/Caribe',
    'TipoViaje':'Un viaje',
    'FechaInicio':'20/06/2019',
    'FechaFin':'22/06/2019',
    'Edad1':27,
    'Edad2':"",
    'Edad3':"",
    'Edad4':"",
    'Edad5':"",
    'Edad6':"",
    'Edad7':"",
    'Edad8':"",
    'Edad9':"",
    'Edad10':"",
    'Email':'no@no.com',
    'Nombre':'PEDRO',
    'Apellido':'PEREZ',
    'CodigoArea':800,
    'NumeroTelefono':9997777,
    'dr':"",
    'cn':'(direct)',
    'cs':'(direct)',
    'cm':'(none)',
    'ck':'(not set 5)',
    'cc':'(not set 5)',
    'ua':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
    'ref':'ar.ec.universal-assistance.com',
    'sr':'1366x768',
    'vp':'1366x728'
}
resp = requests.post(url = url, data = data )

print(resp.text)
```

I expect the html of "https://ar.ec.universal-assistance.com/ofertas-asistencia-al-viajero"

That would be the next page from first url.